# zsh parse error: "(eval):1: parse error near `)'"

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I open terminal, I receive this message:

```
Last login: Fri Jan 17 11:02:25 on ttys000
(eval):1: parse error near `)'
(eval):1: parse error near `)'
```

It prints twice, but I only have four ")" in my .zshrc file, and none of them seem to be causing any issues. I've looked around the web for solutions, but I haven't found many that seem to address this problem.

My .zshrc file looks like this:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
```

(Some code removed for brevity...)

```
# Which plugins would you like to load?

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

```
# My personal Add-ons:

# open VSCode via "code"
function code {
    if [[ $# = 0 ]]
    then
        open -a "Visual Studio Code"
    else
        local argPath="$1"
        [[ $1 = /* ]] && argPath="$1" || argPath="$PWD/${1#./}"
        open -a "Visual Studio Code" "$argPath"
    fi
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted certainly isn't causing the problem, because there aren't *any* `)`.

Comment: See Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages.
"[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"
"[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
"[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". It's important to post code that duplicates the problem. Without that we can't help.

Comment: @theTinMan I understand that; I don't know how to reproduce the issue, though, as I don't know where it's coming from. I hoped that someone would have experienced the same and could let me know which file to look in. I posted the .zshrc because I figured it would be asked for eventually anyway.

Also, why did you edit my post to remove the "thanks" at the bottom?

Comment: "There’s no need to include greetings and sign-offs such as “Hi everyone!” and “Thanks – hope to get an answer soon” in the question. These will often be edited out by other users, as they’re basically a distraction. Greetings at the start of a question are particularly useless as they can take up valuable space in the snippet displayed in the question list." - https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ which is a highly recommended page to read. The author of it has the highest reputation of anyone on SO.